# Qt process slots in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to implement a mechanism where slots will be handled in a separate thread. Obviously such an implementation will not work, I need a way to prevent the function from completing and while still being able to receive signals. How to implement this?

```
void connect() {
    t_ = std::thread(&myclass::start, this);
    }
    

void start() { 

QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket;

QObject::connect(
          socket, &QAbstractSocket::connected, this,
          [this]() {
            //do1()
          },
          Qt::DirectConnection);

QObject::connect(
          socket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, this,
          [this]() {
            //do2()
          },
          Qt::DirectConnection);

QObject::connect(
          socket, &QAbstractSocket::readyRead, this,
          [this]() {
            //do3()
          },
          Qt::DirectConnection);
    
    }
```

Comment: In my code I found it simpler to create the socket inside the worker thread.

Comment: This example may help you: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html)

Comment: "Obviously such an implementation will not work": 
why do you think that is true? [read up on thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)